# Count unique results in one column which have a given value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working with a database of product tests. Each tested device has a unique identifier, a datetime stamp, and a batch of tests with a result for each. The final test is named 'Finished', with a pass or fail reflecting the batch overall.

I'm trying to write a query in SQL Server 2008 which will give me a count of the number of devices which have passed overall first time, grouped by date.

Limiting my results to November onwards, I can list how many times each device has been tested with:

```
SELECT UID, COUNT (UID) AS Attempts
FROM [dbase].[dbo].[tbl_results]
where TestName = 'Finished'
  and Stamp > '2013-11-01'
GROUP BY UID
ORDER BY Attempts
```

However, this doesn't give me a count, a grouping by date, or any idea whether that batch was a pass or a fail. On my first attempt I included "where Pass = 'P'", but then realised that just excluded all the failures resulting in false information.

I THINK I need to find a way to make this query show only products where Attempts = 1 (with a subquery?), then join that output with the results table and counting Pass = 'P', but I can't figure out the syntax of the join command.

I'm not looking for code - I'd much rather someone could just give me some advice. I've only been using SQL for about two days... Please could someone give me a hand?

Thanks!

Tom

Sample Data:

```
UID         Pass    TestName    Stamp
97292       P       Finished    02/12/2013 07:43
97567       F       Finished    03/12/2013 13:21
97567       P       Finished    03/12/2013 13:25
97568       P       Finished    03/12/2013 12:42
97569       P       Finished    03/12/2013 12:28
97570       P       Finished    03/12/2013 11:56
97571       F       Finished    03/12/2013 11:40
97571       P       Finished    03/12/2013 11:44
97572       F       Finished    03/12/2013 11:23
```

This data is already ordered by UID - it shows that 97292 passed first time (single result, value P), 97567 passed second time (two results, P and F), and 97572 was only tested once but failed.

Ideal Output:

```
Date        Passed First Time
02/12/2013  45
03/12/2013  37
04/12/2013  62
```

Comment: Do your `count(UID)` in a sub-query, something like: `Select *, (select count(UID) from tbl_results t2 where t1=t2) from tbl_results where TestName = 'Finished'
  and Stamp > '2013-11-01'
GROUP BY stamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted it! Now works like a charm. Thanks to bummi and Kiril for your advice.

In case anyone needs this in future - once I got the hang of things I added a few extra features as well.

```
SELECT u.UID
      ,TestRig
      ,CONVERT (Date, [Stamp]) AS Date
      ,Description
FROM (
     SELECT UID
           ,COUNT (UID) AS Attempts
     FROM [dbase].[dbo].[tbl_results]
     where TestRig IN ('RigOne', 'RigTwo')
       and TestName = 'Finished'
       and Stamp > '2013-12-01'
     GROUP BY UID) AS u 

JOIN (
     SELECT UID
           ,Pass
           ,TestName
           ,Stamp
           ,TestRig
           ,Description
     FROM [dbase].[dbo].[tbl_results]
     ) AS r
ON (u.UID = r.UID)
where u.Attempts = 1
  and r.Pass = 'P'
  and TestRig IN ('RigOne', 'RigTwo')
  and TestName = 'Finished'
  and Stamp > '2013-12-01'
  and Pass = 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery for products with only one attempt could look like:

```
Select UID 
from tbl_results
Where TestName='Finished'
Group by UID
Having Count(*)=1
```

the subquery can be joined with tbl_results by using an alias and joining via UID, filtered for Testname, Pass and DateStamp.
For the grouping you will have to extract the datepart from Stamp:
On SQL-Server 2008 + you can use `CONVERT (STAMP, GETDATE())`
on prior versions you will have to use e.g. `CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), STAMP, 112) as Date)`

So the complete SQL could look like:

```
Select CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), STAMP, 112) as Date) as [Date]
,COUNT(*) as [Passed First Time]
from tbl_results
join
(
Select UID 
from tbl_results
Where TestName='Finished'
Group by UID
Having Count(*)=1
) x on x.UID=tbl_results.UID
Where TestName='Finished' and Pass='P' and Stamp > '2013-11-01'
Group by  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), STAMP, 112) as Date)
ORDER BY CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), STAMP, 112) as Date)
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply!

The code runs successfully, but for some reason the first part only returns 6 results, which obviously throws off the code below. I've just done an Excel vlookup to check the results and there are around 600 UIDs in this range which only have one occurrence of TestName = 'Finished' (and have therefore only been tested once), at least 530 of which were first time passes. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Ok, I understood `have passed overall first time` if TestName = 'Finished' can occur more than once per UID you will have to include `Where TestName='Finished'` to the inner SQL after `from tbl_results`. You might add some example data and expected output to your question.

Comment: I've added more information above as requested. My first batch of code gives me an accurate assessment of how many times each UIN has been through the test, with the number of completed test batches listed as 'Attempts' - I think my best bet so far would be to try to integrate that code with your suggestion.